# Animating Text to Appear as Div Transforms

Tags: html, css

In my [site](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNvJBX) (here's the codepen version) I'm trying to make it so that when the user hovers over a `div` it `transition`s and the background changes, the width changes and text appears. I'm having a hard time on the text.

Also since this is my first website I'm open to any opinions from people. Specifically ways I can improve my code and making it more concise.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: @PlatinumGlasses Please provide any examples to get response from this group. Otherwise, your question will be downvoted. Also please read the following, before posting questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Effects like these are pretty for the eye, but that's where it stops. In most cases, animations like this distract users from the content. I'd thus advise against using it. *Maybe* If you'd improve the speed and response time it could be something, but even then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stick to my comment, I don't think you should do this on a production site. But here's what you can do: http://codepen.io/BramVanroy/pen/WvMxLd Here it is in [fullscreen](http://codepen.io/BramVanroy/full/WvMxLd/).

**Don't over-use flex. Only when you need it. In your case, you only need to set it to the wrapper. Not to the body.**

Important parts of the code for flex:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box:hover {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

And for the change of text:

```
.box p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.box:hover p {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!

I took notes on the code you used and it taught me a lot. I didn't realise how redundant and how useless some of what I put was. I'll make sure to keep these in mind in my further projects!

Comment: @PlatinumGlasses As with many things, less is often more. :-) If this helped you, please +1 or accept my answer by clicking the check mark on the left, and/or the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a span inside all of the divs, than using this selector -> `.right_slider:hover span.[chosen class for the spans, to be equal for all of them]` you can do what you want with your text, images and so on..

here's a quick example just to show the concept:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNVzdM

hope it helps! BTW, love that animation, very nice ;)